# Why does VS Code point out a re-definition of a function as an error?

Tags: python, function, visual-studio-code

Consider the code below:

```
def hello():
    print("First hello")


def hello():
    print("Second hello")


hello()
```

While running this code in a terminal will output *Second hello*, VS Code insists that there is an error, highlighting it as such with a message that states "function already defined".

My assumption was that it would work the same way redefining variables does. The second definition overrides the first.

So why would VS Code ignore the redefinition of a variable but not of a function? What's the logic behind it?

Comment: Reassigning a new value to a variable is a pretty common thing, but redefining a function is sufficiently usual that linters will usually flag it as something you might not have meant to do.  It's not a runtime error, it's more of a hint from the IDE that you may have done a typo.

Comment: name the second function `hello2` and then add the line `hello = hello2`

Comment: or just delete the first function since it's dead code?  :P